# What is the meaning of 立腹

Tags: translation, meaning

I am in a chat-community where in a room called "manga and anime" we have a background image, where you can see those two kanji. [Google](https://translate.google.de/?hl=de#ja/en/%E7%AB%8B%E8%85%B9) translates it as *anger, offense*, however i don't see the reasoning for something like this to be in the background.

I have uploaded a screenshot from our chatchannel-background:

[image: background]

Those are the correct kanji, right? What is the meaning of those two kanji if they are not used in any context, if they just stand on their own?

Comment: Well, the girl on the pic appears to be annoyed so maybe it's fitting...

Comment: On a related note, you can make a verb out of it by "switching" the kanji:  腹（が）立つ and 腹（を）立てる.  Although if you leave out the particle, you must rendaku the 立, so the first syllable becomes ダ.

Comment: (Additional Information) We generally use not 立腹 but ご立腹.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kanji means anger, and the expression of the girl's face is expressing anger toward her dog for not moving. So it's quite fit.

Answer (score 1):

立腹 is a noun meaning "getting angry." You can verbalize it by saying "立腹する." A more colloquial form of 立腹する is 腹を立てる. Perhaps 立腹 came from 腹を立てる. I can't tell which one of a boy and dog got angry from the cartoon.